# Subclassed RelativeLayout onDraw() method not called in ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Here's a little background into what I'm trying to achieve, in order to help make my question a bit more clear...I'm creating a Navigation Drawer where each item in the ListView looks similar to the following:

[image: ListItem]

However, I need to be able to change the color of the right side border (the blue) to a variety of different colors programmatically, so while playing around with a solution, I decided to extend a `RelativeLayout` and draw the line in the `onDraw(Canvas c);` method.  My `RelativeLayout` code is as follows:

```
public class CustomRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    private final Paint paint = new Paint();

    public CustomRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

        //Other Constructors

    private void init() {
        setPaintColor(Color.argb(128, 0, 0, 0));
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawLine(getMeasuredWidth() - 1, 0, getMeasuredWidth() - 1, getMeasuredHeight(), paint);
    }

    public void setPaintColor(int color){
        paint.setColor(color);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

My `NavigationDrawer`'s `ListView` also contains a header that uses this class, and it works fine as a header view.  However, for each individual `ListView` item, the border isn't present.  I've debugged my solution, and found that my subclassed `RelativeLayout`'s `onDraw(Canvas c);` method is called for the header view, but isn't called for each of the `ListView`'s child views provided by my `ArrayAdapter<String>`.

I know there are other ways to handle this, such as using a default `View`, setting it's background to the color I want, and aligning it to the right - but that's not my question.  My question is why is my `CustomRelativeLayout`'s `onDraw(Canvas c);` method is called for the `ListView`'s header view, and not for each of the Views provided by my adapter?  Any insight into this behavior would be appreciated.  Also, here are the `CustomArrayAdapter` and `nav_drawer_item.xml` used with the `ListView` in case they're helpful:

```
public class SimpleDrawerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public SimpleDrawerAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            String[] sections) {
        super(context, resource, sections);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        RelativeLayout container = null;

        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
            container = (CustomRelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_drawer_item, parent, false);
        } else {
            container = (CustomRelativeLayout) convertView;
        }

        ((TextView)container.findViewById(R.id.nav_item_text)).setText(getItem(position));

        return container;
    }

}
```

nav_drawer_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.mypackage.views.CustomRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/nav_item_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/nav_drawer_grey"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_large"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/navigation_drawer_item_margin"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp" />

</com.mypackage.views.CustomRelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing the WILL_NOT_DRAW flag by calling [setWillNotDraw](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setWillNotDraw(boolean)) method in your custom layout?

Comment: Nice, this fixed the issue.  I'm guessing ListView makes optimizations for ViewGroups by setting this flag to true?  Post this as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Glad it helped. I believe ViewGroups have this enabled by default, yes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried clearing the `WILL_NOT_DRAW` flag by calling [setWillNotDraw](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setWillNotDraw%28boolean%29) method in your custom layout?

> If this view doesn't do any drawing on its own, set this flag to allow
>   further optimizations. By default, this flag is not set on View, but
>   could be set on some View subclasses such as ViewGroup. Typically, if
>   you override onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas) you should clear this
>   flag.

Answer (score -1):

just call it yourself each time you iterate over the list

```
   if(convertView == null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
                container = (CustomRelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_drawer_item,
parent, false);


if(container!=null){
container.draw()
}


            } else {
                container = (CustomRelativeLayout) convertView;

if(container!=null){
container.draw()
}
        }
```

Comment: The draw method requires a canvas as a parameter.  Also, this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" is set the same for the header and the items in the list?

Comment: that line and this oneandroid:layout_margin="@dimen/navigation_drawer_item_margin" may be causing it to draw outside your screen since the widht dosnt adjust with the layout....